# Error in upgrading to Service Pack 1 in visual studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

[image]I have installed Visual Studio 2010 professional version and installation is successful. When I open visual studio, the dialog in first image came and clicked on the link. While installing SP1,the dialog in second image came.How can I solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

log file is

Comment: Is Visual Studio 2010 supported on the version of Windows (looks like 10 in the screenshot...?). I suspect not.

Comment: Also, did you try reading the log file? There might be a clue in there.

Comment: yes. It is supported.